# Display image if array is empty

Tags: php, foreach

I am struggling with a single array. I have a slider that is pulling data out of an array and displaying them as fancybox. It works perfectly fine if there's data in array, but if there is no data in it, the infinite loop starts on loading.

Basically, what I want to accomplish is to add a single image (for example : No images at this time.jpg) on it.

Here's a code (original):

```
<ul class="sliders-wrap-inner">
<?php 
$gallery = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'gallery_bid', true);
else foreach($gallery as $gale ) {
?>
<li>
<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="<?php echo $gale['image-larger']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $gale['image-larger']; ?>" alt="" /></a>                                         
</li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Edited code (my attempt to complete it)

```
<ul class="sliders-wrap-inner">
    <?php 
    $gallery = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'gallery_bid', true);
    if(empty($gallery))
    echo 'There are no images!';
    else foreach($gallery as $gale ) {
    ?>
    <li>
    <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="<?php echo $gale['image-larger']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $gale['image-larger']; ?>" alt="" /></a>                                         
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
    </ul>
```

Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: How does an empty array cause an infinite loop in a foreach? If anything, it would skip right past it?

Comment: @Fluffeh Most probably some vague Wordpress plugin is acting buggy when no images are returned.

Comment: @Fluffeh what i actually meant to say is that foreach is causing no image to load and fancbox load icon is loading (spinning) all the time.

Comment: @evul Can you post the original code you were using and post any changes below that? When you change your code for code from an answer, all answers will stop making sense...

Comment: @jeroen Perhaps I did what you asked for. Sorry about that.

Comment: That doesn't really look like what you originally posted, where does that `else` come from all of a sudden?

Comment: Please see the answer I have provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$Array = array();
$Array_Count = count($Array);

if ($Array_Count === 0){
  // echo image here
}else foreach($Array AS $Key => $Value){
  // work with array
}
```

OR more fitting for what you've provided:

```
<ul class="sliders-wrap-inner">
    <?php
        $Gallery = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'gallery_bid', true);
        if (count($Gallery) === 0){
            // print no image here The slider should adjust automatically depending on the fed images
        }else foreach($Gallery AS $Gale){
            echo '<li>';
            echo '<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="'.$Gale['image-larger'].'"><img src="'.$Gale['image-larger'].'" alt=""></a>';
            echo '</li>';
        } ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you buddy but that didn't work. I tried to echo an image inside it or simple text but neither worked. It still loads no images at all. (Spinning loading icon)

Comment: Then,are you sure that you're pointing to an image which exists, in a directory which is accessible to the user that the webservice is running as & appending the correct file extension? From studying the code. It should be contained in `$Gale['image-larger']`. Could you update your question to show the contents?

Comment: I am sure there's nothing in the loop (Foreach), that's why I was looking for alternative image to be displayed. For some reason it still tries to load the images that don't exist, instead of showing the echo src image I put in code you provided.

Comment: Then your first debugging steps would be to comment out all client sided output, such as HTML, work with a white page, var_dump the array to see the contents, then echo out the count of the array. Report back once you've got that information

Comment: @evul May I ask what happened on following my debugging steps?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have an infinite loop but you probably don't see anything / things go wrong because the closing `}` is at the wrong place. Somewhere at the end of your document perhaps?

Move the closing `}` to between the `</li>` and the `</ul>`:

```
<li>
<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="<?php echo $gale['image-larger']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $gale['image-larger']; ?>" alt="" /></a>
</li>
<?php
}
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sorry, it looks like i didn't paste whole code. I actually have the closing } at the end of li and ul.

Comment: @evul This is essentially a copy and paste, the minor change actually fixes the problem you're encountering. The closing `</li>` is now before the closing brace, when in your example the closing tag is after the closing brace

Comment: @DarylGill oh I see, i fixed it but i still want to display something if $gallery is empty, I tried with if(empty($gallery)) but it didn't do the trick.

Comment: @evul And what is that `endif` doing there? Can you post the actual code you are using including the complete blocks / loops?

Comment: @DarylGill yes, I have edited op.